# Could I custom Class inherit from Class Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, inheritance

In Swift 4.1,I want custom a new class named Nodes,this class inherit from class Array:

```
class Node {
    //it is not important...
}

class Nodes: Array<Node> {  //#1

}
```

But there are one compiling error in line #1 :

> Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Array'

Is it possible to inherit from Array? or I misunderstand something??? thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inherit from `Array`, because it is a `struct`. Instead, try to look at [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) + [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) protocols. These two allow you to implement most of array features.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** `Arrays` are not classes in general. They are structs which can not be inherited in any case.